# How can I fix mpdf Permission denied in PHP

Tags: php, excel, pdf, mpdf, phpspreadsheet

I try to create a PDF from a XLSX data. I use Mpdf and PhpSpreadsheet. 
I got this error what do i wrong?

I got this code:

```
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReaderForFile("Leistungsbericht/Vorlage_M4cM4rco.xlsx");
$Vorlage2=$reader->load("Leistungsbericht/Vorlage_M4cM4rco.xlsx");

$Vorlage2->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridLines(false);
$Vorlage2->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($Vorlage2, 'Mpdf');

$writer->save('Leistungsbericht/M4cM4rcotest.pdf');
```

and this Fatal Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: DirectoryIterator::__construct(/mnt/shared/tmp): 
failed to open dir: Permission denied in /mnt/web320/c1/88/59295888/htdocs/Test2/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php:87 
Stack trace: 
0 /mnt/web320/c1/88/59295888/htdocs/Test2/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php(87): DirectoryIterator->__construct('/mnt/shared/tmp') 
#1 /mnt/web320/c1/88/59295888/htdocs/Test2/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(9481): Mpdf\Cache->clearOld() 
#2 /mnt/web320/c1/88/59295888/htdocs/Test2/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Pdf/Mpdf.php(96): Mpdf\Mpdf->Output('', 'S') 
#3 /mnt/web320/c1/88/59295888/htdocs/Test2/Leistungs2.php(78): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Mpdf->save('Leistungsberich...')
#4 /mnt/web320/c1/88/59295888/htdocs/Test2/Leistungs2.php(182): hhh() #5 {main} thrown in /mnt/web320/c1/88/59295888/htdocs/Test2/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php on line 87
```

Comment: It's not PHP fault. Apply write permissions for script run user for directory `/mnt/shared/tmp`.

`chmod -R o+w /mnt/shared/tmp` ...

Comment: That was my first try but I did not find the directory... I searched the complete vendor order..

Comment: what is the result of method `sys_get_temp_dir` call?

Comment: The result is: `/var/tmp/`

Comment: hmm... did you try to chane default cache directory path?  https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/folders-for-temporary-files.html

Comment: Yeah and I use a directory where I can save excel files with PHP. And for experemental I set the directory to 777 permissions. But I got the same result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531935/mpdf-change-temp-path-composer-package/